# How to add constraint on a varchar column to have at least one non numeric character

Tags: sql-server, database-design, constraint, table, ddl

I am trying to implement some constraints on tables so that there is no tampering of the data from what is expected.

One of the constraints is on a varchar column. It should at least contain one non-numeric character.

How can I implement this constraint in SQL Server, and if I implement it, What will be the effect on the performance if any?

Answer (score 2):

A check constraint with a `LIKE` expression could be used to ensure at least one non-numeric character exists:

```
CHECK (YourColumn LIKE '%[^0-9]%')
```

The `0-9` range there might not be exactly right for you, depending on the collation of the `varchar` column. For example, using the common `Latin1_General_CI_AS` collation, the following additional characters would be considered numeric by the `0-9` test:

```
²
³
¹
¼
½
¾
```

If that is a concern, expand the range explicitly:

```
CHECK (YourColumn LIKE '%[^0123456789]%')
```

I would expect negligible performance impact in either case.